# Change class of span next to the radio button a user clicked

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm generating some feedback for some multiple choice questions using Angular.js. I'm trying to show the feedback next to the radio button the user clicked but I can only seem to show it after every radio button because of ng-repeat. So I figured the best option would be to hide all the feedback in spans and change the class of the span next to where the user clicked but I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="testController" ng-submit="submit()"> 

  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">

    <div>{{question.Question}}</div>

    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected[$index]" value="A" name="{{question.id}}" />{{question.A}}
    <span class="hide">{{feedback[$index]}}</span><br />

    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected[$index]" value="B" name="{{question.id}}" />{{question.B}}
    <span class="hide">{{feedback[$index]}}</span><br />

    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected[$index]" value="C" name="{{question.id}}" />{{question.C}}
    <span class="hide">{{feedback[$index]}}</span><br />

    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected[$index]" value="D" name="{{question.id}}" />{{question.D}}
    <span class="hide">{{feedback[$index]}}</span><br />

  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Script:

```
angular.module('nodeServerApp')
.controller('testController', function ($scope) {

 $scope.questions = 
 [
     {
         "id": 0,
         "Question": "Is C the right answer?",
         "A": "This is choice A.",
         "B": "This is choice B.",
         "C": "This is choice C.",
         "D": "This is choice D.",
         "Answer": "C"
     },
     {
         "id": 1,
         "Question": "Is A the right answer?",
         "A": "This is choice A.",
         "B": "This is choice B.",
         "C": "This is choice C.",
         "D": "This is choice D.",
         "Answer": "A"
     },
     {
         "id": 2,
         "Question": "Is D the right answer?",
         "A": "This is choice A.",
         "B": "This is choice B.",
         "C": "This is choice C.",
         "D": "This is choice D.",
         "Answer": "D"
     }
 ];

 $scope.selected = [];
 $scope.feedback = [];

 $scope.submit = function () {

     if ($scope.selected.length < 3) {
         alert("Please answer all questions.");
     }
     else {
         for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
             if (angular.equals($scope.selected[i], $scope.questions[i].Answer) === false) {
                 $scope.feedback[i] = "Incorrect";
             }
             else {
                 $scope.feedback[i] = "Correct";
             }
         }
     }

 };

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) to show the feedback next to the selected answer:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="selected[$index]" value="A" name="{{question.id}}" />{{question.A}}
<span ng-show='answers[$index] == "A"'>{{feedback[$index]}}</span>

<input type="radio" ng-model="selected[$index]" value="B" name="{{question.id}}" />{{question.A}}
<span ng-show='answers[$index] == "B"'>{{feedback[$index]}}</span>
```

etc.